# Does convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ imply the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ is a convergent series. Does this imply that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because $x_n\to 0$.${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $x_n=\sum_{k=0}^nx_k-\sum_{h=0}^{n-1}x_h$.